# Use map_blocks to compute a heap based on the contents of each block

Tags: dask

I've created a Dask cluster on my laptop, and have loaded a NetCDF dataset on it using xarray.open_dataset('some_data.nc',chunks={'lat':'auto', 'lon':'auto', 'time':-1})

I've converted this to a distributed array of time series, ts, one per (lat,lon) pair. For this array, ts.chunks is:
((1555200, 1555200, 1555200, 1555200, 1555200, 1555200), (12,))

Now what I'd like to do is create one heapq per chunk with entries computed one per row of each chunk. I was hoping I could use map_blocks for this, but I don't see how. Also, I want to do some reduction based on those heaps.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this would be to switch to Dask delayed.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html